# How to use automapper in orderby clause with dynamic linq?

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, sql-order-by, automapper

I'm using orderProperties variable as dynamic linq and I need to use AutoMapper in OrderBy clause. I need to map "MyColumn" property from Resource class to other property from ResourceViewModel class. 
Query() returns IQuerable of Resource. For example I have in Resouce class MyColumn property and I need to map it to MyOtherColumn, which is in ResourceViewModel. 
Any ideas how to do that?

```
string orderProperties = "MyColumn Ascending";

var orderList = _resourceRepository.Query()
                                   .OrderBy(orderProperties)
                                   .Select(Mapper.Map<Resource, ResourceViewModel>);
```

Comment: You need to post the code for whatever type the Query() method returns, plus your view model that you map too.

Comment: Query() returns IQuerable<Resource>. For example I have in Resouce class MyColumn property and I need to map it to MyOtherColumn, which is in ResourceViewModel.

Answer (score 1):

I would try another approach:

- store the result of my query in a variable
- and then translate that resultset using automapper.

**The ordering should work completely independent from automapper.**  Autommapper only "translates" the stuff.

something like this:

```
string orderProperties = "MyColumn Ascending";

var orderList = _resourceRepository.Query()
                                   .OrderBy(orderProperties)
                                   .ToList();
Mapper.CreateMap<IList<Resource>, IList<ResourceViewModel>>();
var results = Mapper.Map<IList<Resource>>(orderList);
```

HTH

Comment: +1 - FYI, `Mapper.CreateMap` only needs to be called once - you do not need to call it every time you want to map an object to another one. I usually do this in the static constructor of the repository.

Comment: Yeah completely correct. I usually put in a configuration class/project usually where the DI container config lives in order to do the Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid(); as soon as possible. I learn this the hard way ;(